# How to calculate currency conversion for ZARCAD for a specific date with GOOGLEFINANCE?

Tags: google-sheets, currency, google-finance

I have a Google sheet that I use multiple currencies in. I purchase a product on a specific date and I want to lock in the conversion for that date. However, I have not been able to do that with all the different formulas that I have tried. I keep getting an error. Here is the formula that I am using.
=J283*GOOGLEFINANCE("ZARCAD","price",date(2021,4,9),date(2021,4,11))
Column J is the column with the price in the currency of purchase. I need to convert it into Canadian dollars. It works if I want the current price of the currency, but not for the historical data.
The error is:
Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Date' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15k1V0ZE3adpCDpfDNyv34tqSPEuFNfhdGE2aNPxsVco/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can't access the sheet you provided.

Comment: It should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are using creates a 2D array as below:
[image]

In order to be able to use a function that expects number values (like `MULTIPLY`), you have to index a part of the 2D array that is a number.

For example, to multiply the first "Close" value of 0.08575243, you have to tell the fomula to use that value for the calculation with the built-in `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("ZARCAD","price",date(2021,4,9),date(2021,4,11)),2,2)
```

If you wish to specify a different part of the array, just change the `2,2` (row, column) at the end to any numbers that point to the value in the array that you wish to use. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en), you can find the documentation for `INDEX`.